# Using AutoHotKey, how can I make mouse as a keyboard without repeat when I hold it?

Tags: autohotkey

What really I want is: When I press and hold "up"arrow, it will do left click and hold it (no repeat) within certain coordinate (such as 1226, 631).
And when I release the "up"arrow, it will stop holding the left click.

Please help me, I need it very much... Thank.
I want to play game in bluestack with keyboard.

Maybe it can be a hint:

```
~~~
Moving the Mouse Cursor via the Keyboard
~~~
*#up::MouseMove, 0, -10, 0, R  ; Win+UpArrow hotkey => Move cursor upward
*#Down::MouseMove, 0, 10, 0, R  ; Win+DownArrow => Move cursor downward
*#Left::MouseMove, -10, 0, 0, R  ; Win+LeftArrow => Move cursor to the left
*#Right::MouseMove, 10, 0, 0, R  ; Win+RightArrow => Move cursor to the right

*<#RCtrl::  ; LeftWin + RightControl => Left-click (hold down Control/Shift to Control-Click or Shift-Click).
SendEvent {Blind}{LButton down}
KeyWait RCtrl  ; Prevents keyboard auto-repeat from repeating the mouse click.
SendEvent {Blind}{LButton up}
return

*<#AppsKey::  ; LeftWin + AppsKey => Right-click
SendEvent {Blind}{RButton down}
KeyWait AppsKey  ; Prevents keyboard auto-repeat from repeating the mouse click.
SendEvent {Blind}{RButton up}
return
~~~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your question (and the script does nothing to support it). But it looks like you want the following:

Press <kbd>^</kbd> = Press Left Mouse button (No repeat). Added MouseMove to jump to the coordinates.

```
Up::
MouseMove, 1226, 631, 0
;ToolTip, 1
Send, {LButton Down}
KeyWait, Up
;ToolTip, 2
Send, {LButton Up}
Return
```

Comment: It's my script to play zenonia 5 in bluestack (Resolution 1366X768):

*z::MouseClick left, 1226, 631
return

*x::MouseMove, 209, 565
return

;NOTE
;z = attack
;x = go to d-pad, use your mouse to move.

This ("x" button (to point the d-pad instantly) + mouse to move)  bother me enough to move although it help me a little. I wish, I can change this ("x" button + mouse to move) with "up","down", rigth", and "left" to move.
If I use with my simple script above, when I hold the button, it will do auto-repeat. What must I do so that it won't repeat?
Thank for answer my question..

Comment: I updated the answer, so it will not auto repeat.

Comment: that's it!! thank very much, bro Robert. Then, how to add certain coordinate to "up" button?

what I mean coordinate is like this: 
*z::MouseClick left, 1226, 631. "1226, 631" is the coordinate destination.

Comment: Added MouseMove to the script